# Call Method from User Control in Parent with Unique Parameters

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have a User Control that has a Textbox and a Button:

```
<TextBox Grid.Row="1" Text="SampleText" VerticalContentAlignment="Center"  />
<Button Name="btnBrowse" Click="btnBrowse_Click" Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Width="50" Content="..." />
```

I then call this on my Main Window:

```
<UserControls:MyTextbox Grid.Row="0" />
```

I have a method on my Main Window (parent):

```
public void ShowAMessage(string code)
{
    MessageBox.Show(code);
}
```

So now I wanna call the `ShowAMessage` on the parent from my `UserControl`, and it should pass a unique parameter called `code`. Is there some way to "declare" a unique code when importing the `UserControl`, that then I could pass to the `ShowAMessage` method?

I was thinking of something like this:

```
<UserControls:MyTextbox Grid.Row="0" Code="Hello There" />
<UserControls:MyTextbox Grid.Row="0" Code="Welcome" />
```

And then on the `btnBrowse_Click`:

```
((ParentWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).ShowAMessage(Code);
```

But this doesn't work, gives me an `InvalidCastException`

Btw, I already declare the `Code` variable on the `UserControl` as well:

```
private string code;
public string Code
{
    get { return code; }
    set { code = value; }
}
```

Comment: You can use [Window.GetWindow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.window.getwindow) method inside btnBrowse_Click to find the parent Window. Then cast it to ParentWindow and call ShowAMessage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to recreate the same situation and the code should work, try to see if you're casting the `Application.Current.MainWindow` to the right type.

The only problem I can see there is if the parent window of your `UserControl` is not the starting window of the application.

If that's the case, instead of using `Application.Current.MainWindow`, you can use `Window.GetWindow(this)`. That should return the parent window of the parameter.

Personal tip for the property, if you just get and set the backing field, you can just write this:
`Public string Code { get; set; }`
It should do the same thing.